# Merge two columns filter unique values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Iḿ trying to merge the text from two columns (A2:A and D2:D). But i need to filter to only show the unique values of those merged two columns. And place it on a different location on the sheet. The list in column H needs to be dynamic. Because more values can be added to the sheet.

How can i achieve this?

[image: Merge col google sheets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest a shorter variant and a single array formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(unique(query(A2:A&" "&D2:D,"where not Col1 = ' '")))`

Comment: This is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

In Column H, make a formula    =concatenate(A2," ",D2) in row 2

Copy the formula down (to as many rows as data is available in sheet1)

In I2 make the formula =UNIQUE(H2:H)

You will get the unique values

It will be dynamic

Comment: The list in column H needs to be dynamic. Because more values can be added to the sheet.

Comment: Copy the formula in sheet 2 till whatever be the possible last row.